# Python name generator

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x, random

This is a basic name generator I just wrote and want some feedback.
It basically chooses between a vowel or a consonant and appends it to a string. Note that it never puts two vowels or two consonants directly together, as it checks for that.

```
import random

vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z']

def generate_name(length):
    if length <= 0:
        return False

    full_syl = ''
    for i in range(length):
        decision = random.choice(('consonant', 'vowel'))

        if full_syl[-1:].lower() in vowels:
            decision = 'consonant'
        if full_syl[-1:].lower() in consonants:
            decision = 'vowel'

        if decision == 'consonant':
            syl_choice = random.choice(consonants)
        else:
            syl_choice = random.choice(vowels)

        if full_syl == '':
            full_syl += syl_choice.upper()
        else:
            full_syl += syl_choice

    return full_syl


for i in range(100):
    length = random.randint(3, 10)
    print(generate_name(length))
```

Answer (score 3):

Why does `generate_name(0)` return `False`? I would expect an empty string `''`, or maybe `None`.

---

Rather than check `if full_syl == '':` (not a great name, by the way; why not just `name`?) during the loop, I would build the whole name in lowercase then  use [`str.title`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title): `return full_syl.title()`. This removes both `.upper` and `.lower` from the `for`loop, simplifying the code.

---

Why pick every letter randomly? In this part:

```
decision = random.choice(('consonant', 'vowel'))

if full_syl[-1:].lower() in vowels:
    decision = 'consonant'
if full_syl[-1:].lower() in consonants:
    decision = 'vowel'
```

the first value of `decision` is ignored for every letter but the first. If you want strict alternation, you only need to randomly pick the type of the *first* letter. You could even use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to switch back and forth between `vowels` and `consonants` for each pick.

---

Rather than keep adding letters to a string, I would probably build a list or iterator of letters then [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them. Otherwise you create many unnecessary string objects for the partial names, which are immediately discarded.